# how to display the label which have two categorys with background and foreground

Tags: c#, uwp, listviewitem

The design image is [image]

This codes is my wrote,but the background is larger then my expection,i hope the data change when i click one category,the selected label highlight
[image]

my codes  is

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="varietyListViewTemplate" x:DataType="local:Category" >
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind title}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="varietyListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="varietyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter 
                        Foreground="#979797"
                        Background="#ffffff"
                        SelectedForeground="#ffffff"
                        SelectedBackground="#fd8c00" 
                        PressedBackground="#fd8c00"
                        SelectedPressedBackground="#fd8c00"
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="#fd8c00"
                        Margin="2"
                        />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--  PointerOverBackground="#fd8c00"
          SelectedForeground="#ffffff"




          PointerOverForeground="#ffffff" -->
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="varietyListView" Grid.Row="0" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=Categorys}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource varietyListViewTemplate}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" Style="{StaticResource varietyListViewStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource varietyListViewItemStyle}"
              ItemClick="varietyListView_ItemClick" >

        </ListView>

        <ListView x:Name="varietyListView2" Grid.Row="0" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=Categorys}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource varietyListViewTemplate}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" Style="{StaticResource varietyListViewStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource varietyListViewItemStyle}"
              ItemClick="varietyListView2_ItemClick" Margin="0,0,0,50">

        </ListView>
        <Frame x:Name="varietyFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>


    <Grid Name="listImage">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you nest Grid to ListviewItem, and then you can change the backgroud of the listitems or just the background of the Grid, and of course you can shape the size of this Grid.

For example:

```
<ListView x:Name="varietyListView" Grid.Row="0" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**That is because** the ListViewItem’s size is larger than actual size of the text. By checking the default template of `ListViewItem`, you will find the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties are specified as following.

```
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>

<x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemMinWidth">88</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemMinHeight">44</x:Double>
```

To find the default template, checking [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) or in ***generic.xaml*** ***`(typical in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic)`*** by searching "Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem".

**To work around this issue**, we can try to make the `ListViewItem` has same size as the actual text by setting `ListViewItem`'s `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` to "0" and use `Margin` to control the spacing between them. So apply the following code should get what you want:

```
<Style x:Key="varietyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter 
                    Foreground="#979797"
                    Background="#ffffff"
                    SelectedForeground="#ffffff"
                    SelectedBackground="#fd8c00" 
                    PressedBackground="#fd8c00"
                    SelectedPressedBackground="#fd8c00"
                    SelectedPointerOverBackground="#fd8c00"
                    Margin="20"
                    />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```